# Info card prioritizing -java flash card applet

Tags: java, graphics, applet, jpanel

I am wanting to make an applet for practice, and my goal is to make a program that displays seven rectangles with info inside of each one. I would also like the cards to display in a random order.

After the cards are displayed, the user should be able to click on the card, and then the card should be removed from the options and be displayed beneath them, in the order that you click them. This may sound confusing, but I basically want the user to be able to prioritize or sort the info cards.

For example, if the cards had dates on them, the user could sort them in order from past to present.

My first idea was to draw rectangles on the screen and get the mouse click x and y to see if the user clicked that card, but I'm sure that there is another way that doesn't have to be that complicated.

I'm sorry that I don't have decent code to post, I would rather not post my messy version. I can update this with code later.

I'm wondering what the best solution would be, because I would like to learn as much as I can from this project.

Comment: *"I am wanting to make an applet for practice.."*  Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: I haven't learned HTML, or JavaScript...

Comment: I know this might be achieved easily with those, but I don't know where to start with that, and I'm trying to learn java already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use panels, and register for action events. Action events don't care the coordinates where your mouse was clicked, but rather if the component was clicked or not. You can use `setActionCommand()` to identify each panel (card) or use some other attribute of your panel that you can read after capturing the event (the `event.getSource()` method returns the component that was clicked).

```
panel.setActionCommand("card1");
panel.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
      if (event.getActionCommand().equals("card1") {
        // do something
      }
   }
}
```

You can also use an existing LayoutManager or adapt or write one to display your panels any way you like.